# Exact Same Poker Hand: Who Wins or Tie?

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

[image]!
Who wins this hand? My friends and I are at a loss. Our hands are located above and below the tabled cards.

Comment: This question has been handled dozens of times on Poker Stack Exchange already. Canonical answers there will be vastly more informative.

Comment: @Nij Is there a canonical answer there you think might be most appropriate? It would help greatly to link to it.

Comment: I could certainly do that. [How to determine the winning hands in poker on Poker SE](http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker).

Comment: We have such answers on this site as well; voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Texas Hold'em counts the best five cards out of the community cards and your hand, which means the both of you have this result:

```
A A J J 10 (Two Pair, Kicker 10)
```

**Because both of your hands are equally ranked, this will result in a Split Pot.**

There are no symbol weights like in other games, where Spades are worth more or less than Diamonds, and never will more than five cards be considered for the final result (in order to give one player a Three Pair, in this case).